# Ubuntu installer not detecting MicroSD

Tags: server, system-installation, sd-card

I need to install Ubuntu Server 13.10 on a MicroSD

When I reach the step where I need to choose the disk to install the system on I don't see my SD card among the options

How to solve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there simply is no option to do so considering how strange your situation is, good luck though and I hope you figure it out.